# Making website but I positioned all the objects one by one using css and it only aligns properly with my monitor

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay so like I am making a website but I aligned all the images to fit inside little grids of like so in the image below:

[image: What it looks like on my monitor]

but on other size monitors or my friend's computer it shows the different red squares outside the image like so:

[image: Website on another size monitor]

I just want it to align properly on all size monitors and screens but I spent so long making the css code perfectly align for me one by one and here is the css code for the red squares as the plus and the minus is what it turns into once someone clicks on it. I have like 9 of these elements all aligned to my webpage size just it only aligns on my monitor and others it all over the place. The code below is the whole website all the code I just want it to align properly on all screen sizes and not just mine without having to change all the numbers I spent hours writing LOL, is there a way I can set the website to align to my monitor size for everyone or something? Here is a live example of the website if you don't run the code below: https://minecraft-inventory-designer.glitch.me/
and also I'm on a MacBook with a 13 inch screen that's the screen size I aligned it to.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
```

```css
.title {
    font-family:minecraft
}
.glasspane {
    
}

/* Six columns side by side */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 16.66%;
}

/* Add a transparency effect for thumnbail images */
.demo {
  opacity: 100;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.tab { margin-left: 40px; }
body {
    background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f6/42/72/f64272bc37d664cf6000fb9a24e47702.png');
    background-position:395px 50px;
    background-size:500px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
  

  }
.plus{
    background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/826141912036802611.png?v=1");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
     padding: 1px 1px;
     height: 45px;
     width: 45px;
}

.plus.minus{
    background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/826141911945445377.png?v=1");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
     padding: 1px 1px;
     height: 45px;
     width: 45px;
}

.plus2{
    background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/826141912036802611.png?v=1");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
     padding: 1px 1px;
     height: 45px;
     width: 45px;
}

.plus2.minus2{
    background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/826141911945445377.png?v=1");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
     padding: 1px 1px;
     height: 45px;
     width: 45px;
}

.plus3{
    background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/826141912036802611.png?v=1");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
     padding: 1px 1px;
     height: 45px;
     width: 45px;
}

.plus3.minus3{
    background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/826141911945445377.png?v=1");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
     padding: 1px 1px;
     height: 45px;
     width: 45px;
}

.plus4{
    background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/826141912036802611.png?v=1");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
     padding: 1px 1px;
     height: 45px;
     width: 45px;
}

.plus4.minus4{
    background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/826141911945445377.png?v=1");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
     padding: 1px 1px;
     height: 45px;
     width: 45px;
}
.plus5{
    background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/826141912036802611.png?v=1");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
     padding: 1px 1px;
     height: 45px;
     width: 45px;
}

.plus5.minus5{
    background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/826141911945445377.png?v=1");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
     padding: 1px 1px;
     height: 45px;
     width: 45px;
}

.plus6{
    background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/826141912036802611.png?v=1");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
     padding: 1px 1px;
     height: 45px;
     width: 45px;
}

.plus6.minus6{
    background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/826141911945445377.png?v=1");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
     padding: 1px 1px;
     height: 45px;
     width: 45px;
}

.plus7{
    background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/826141912036802611.png?v=1");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
     padding: 1px 1px;
     height: 45px;
     width: 45px;
}

.plus7.minus7{
    background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/826141911945445377.png?v=1");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
     padding: 1px 1px;
     height: 45px;
     width: 45px;
}

.plus8{
    background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/826141912036802611.png?v=1");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
     padding: 1px 1px;
     height: 45px;
     width: 45px;
}

.plus8.minus8{
    background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/826141911945445377.png?v=1");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
     padding: 1px 1px;
     height: 45px;
     width: 45px;
}

.plus9{
    background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/826141912036802611.png?v=1");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
     padding: 1px 1px;
     height: 45px;
     width: 45px;
}

.plus9.minus9{
    background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/826141911945445377.png?v=1");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
     padding: 1px 1px;
     height: 45px;
     width: 45px;
}
.pwus:hover, .pwus2:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 140, 186, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
<title>Minecraft Inventory Designer</title>
<center>
<h1 class="title">Minecraft Inventory Designer</h1>
</center>




<a href="#" style="right: 408px; bottom: 387px" class="plus"></a>
<a href="#" style="right: 459px; bottom: 387px" class="plus2"></a>
<a href="#" style="right: 510px; bottom: 387px" class="plus3"></a>
<a href="#" style="right: 561px; bottom: 387px" class="plus4"></a>
<a href="#" style="right: 612px; bottom: 387px" class="plus5"></a>
<a href="#" style="right: 663px; bottom: 387px" class="plus6"></a>
<a href="#" style="right: 714px; bottom: 387px" class="plus7"></a>
<a href="#" style="right: 765px; bottom: 387px" class="plus8"></a>
<a href="#" style="right: 816px; bottom: 387px" class="plus9"></a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="#" style="right: 408px; bottom: 336px" class="plus"></a>
<a href="#" style="right: 459px; bottom: 336px" class="plus2"></a>
<a href="#" style="right: 510px; bottom: 336px" class="plus3"></a>
<a href="#" style="right: 561px; bottom: 336px" class="plus4"></a>
<a href="#" style="right: 612px; bottom: 336px" class="plus5"></a>
<a href="#" style="right: 663px; bottom: 336px" class="plus6"></a>
<a href="#" style="right: 714px; bottom: 336px" class="plus7"></a>
<a href="#" style="right: 765px; bottom: 336px" class="plus8"></a>
<a href="#" style="right: 816px; bottom: 336px" class="plus9"></a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="#" style="right: 408px; bottom: 285px" class="plus"></a>
<a href="#" style="right: 459px; bottom: 285px" class="plus2"></a>
<a href="#" style="right: 510px; bottom: 285px" class="plus3"></a>
<a href="#" style="right: 561px; bottom: 285px" class="plus4"></a>
<a href="#" style="right: 612px; bottom: 285px" class="plus5"></a>
<a href="#" style="right: 663px; bottom: 285px" class="plus6"></a>
<a href="#" style="right: 714px; bottom: 285px" class="plus7"></a>
<a href="#" style="right: 765px; bottom: 285px" class="plus8"></a>
<a href="#" style="right: 816px; bottom: 285px" class="plus9"></a>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
    $(".plus").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("minus") 
    })
       
       $(".plus2").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("minus2")  ; 
       })   
       $(".plus3").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("minus3")  ; 
       })   
       $(".plus4").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("minus4")  ; 
       })   
       $(".plus5").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("minus5")  ; 
       })   
       $(".plus6").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("minus6")  ; 
       })   
       $(".plus7").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("minus7")  ; 
       })   
       $(".plus8").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("minus8")  ; 
       })   
       $(".plus9").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("minus9")  ; 
       })   
       
       
       
       </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Your way is not a way of doing responsive design. Using pixel for a few items is OK, but what did you do is not even close to modern responsive design principles. You need to learn CSS gird and flexbox.

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0):

`position: absolute` will align itself to the nearest relative positioned parent. In your case, you have none so it's aligning itself to the window and `right: whatever` means this many pixels from the right side of the window.

You're going to need to wrap all these elements in a `div` and add `position: relative` to it. This will make all your absolutely positioned elements align to this container instead of the window.

```
HTML:
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" style="right: 408px; bottom: 387px" class="plus"></a>
  ... the rest
</div>

CSS:
.container {
  position: relative;
}
```

This will break your design and you're going to have to reposition all the elements. Aligning `left: whatever` is safer than `right: whatever` since the right edge of elements is likely expanding to match their allowable space.

Going forward you should look into something like CSS grid to perform what you're trying to do in a way that is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You have not made your code responsive, meaning it adjusts to all screens in a manner you think fit... Now to help you, I'm not going to do it for you, but these are all links to help you make your code responsive:

[W3Schools Responsive Web Design](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)
[MDN Responsive Web Design](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design)

Now, a very important CSS *thing(?)* is the [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Media_queries).. *thing(?)*.
This helps you make your CSS style the page and elements differently on different screen sizes.

You could also use (for example) [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) for responsiveness (if you're already using it.)
The grid system is quite time-saving and simple (just give classes)!

Another thing is, using hardcoded widths and heights will not make an element responsive.. consider using percent: (`4%`) instead of px: (`4px`).
Keep in mind that the percentage is relative to the parent element, so if the parent element has a 40% width of the body, and a child element has a 10% width, then the child elements width relative to the body will be 10% * 40% = 4% of the body.
Also: CSS grid and flexbox is pretty crucial if you are going to create more responsive websites